# Jwplayer: set autostart on Android Chrome and iOs Safari

Tags: android, ios, google-chrome, safari, jwplayer

I have a question: I'm using jwplayer for show my videos on Android, iOs ect. Now I see that autostart doesn't work on Android and iOs so I want to replic this behavior anyway. I tried this code but it works only on web...

```
var playerInstance = jwplayer('video-overlay');

playerInstance.setup({
    file: "myFirstVideo.mp4",
    width: "100%",
    title: "Basic Video Embed in overlay",
    description: "A video with a basic title and description"
});
                  
playerInstance.onReady(function() {
    playerInstance.play(true);
    playerInstance.onPlay(function() {
        playerInstance.setControls(false);
        playerInstance.play(true);
    });
});
```

How can fix it? Is there a workaround? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

See https://github.com/jwplayer/jwplayer/issues/1041

Mobile devices do not support autostart. iOS and Android browsers require the command be called from within a user gesture event.

Answer (score 1):

Are you writing this for mobile web or a native app? Autostart is not supported in mobile web, but you can use

```
getAutostart
public Boolean getAutostart()
```

from the Android reference to achieve the same behavior. Autostart is supported in both Android and iOS via the mobile SDKs, which you can find at [developer.jwplayer.com](https://developer.jwplayer.com).